# TYPO3: Custom Extension: label_userfunc custom title in BE list view

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I wrote a custom extension for TYPO3 where I store a list of partners and count the times their logo was displayed in the front-end ...

In the backend the partners get listed by `name`, but I'd like to display also the count of impressions which should be possible per the [**> TYPO3 documentation**](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/singlehtml/#label-userfunc)

in the ovverride:

```
    'label' => 'name',
    'label_userFunc' => 'Newred\\WmPartners\\Userfuncs\\Tca->partnerTitle',
```

in `Classes\Userfuncs\Tca\PartnerTitle.php` :

```
<?php
namespace Newred\WmPartners\Userfuncs\Tca;

public function partnerTitle(&$parameters, $parentObject) {
    $record = \TYPO3\CMS\Backend\Utility\BackendUtility::getRecord($parameters['table'], $parameters['row']['uid']);
    $newTitle = $record['name'];
    $newTitle .= ' (' . substr(strip_tags($record['impressions']), 0, 10) . '...)';
    $parameters['title'] = $newTitle;
}
```

Does someone see where I err, this gives me [no title] in the list

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need your user function to be in the **class** `Newred\WmPartners\Userfuncs\Tca`. To achieve this, create the file `Tca.php` in the folder `wm_partners/Classes/Userfuncs` with the following content:

```
<?php
namespace Newred\WmPartners\Userfuncs;

class Tca
{
    public function partnerTitle(&$parameters, $parentObject)
    {
        $record = \TYPO3\CMS\Backend\Utility\BackendUtility::getRecord($parameters['table'], $parameters['row']['uid']);
        $newTitle = $record['name'];
        $newTitle .= ' (' . substr(strip_tags($record['impressions']), 0, 10) . '...)';
        $parameters['title'] = $newTitle;
    }
}
```

You can always put a `die()` or a debug in there to see if your method is actually called.

Also note that to make this work your class has to be loaded (which is most likely taken care of automatically)

Comment: thanks, your code is spot on, it only took me a moment to realize that the class is only loaded if you disable -> clear cash and enable the extension again ...

Answer (score 1):

In case the brackets were optional and you just wanted to display the value of the field 'impressions' you could alternatively simply use the `label_alt` feature in combination with `label_alt_force`.

```
'label' => 'name',
'label_alt' => 'name,impressions',
'label_alt_force' => true
```

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/Reference/Ctrl/Index.html?highlight=ctrl#label-alt-force

Comment: that would substitute the name though, I looked at this but of course the name remains the main label, it was just very unhandy to open every item to see the amount of impressions ...

Comment: `label_alt_force` supports multiple fields, separated by comma.

Comment: that's indeed good to know, in my case I'm happy with the extra formatting possible applying a function ... but thanks for adding your information ...